# Java app handling for connections getting dropped

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection

My app seems to be hanging overnight because of the connection getting dropped(I think that's the problem.) How can I structure my app so that it can try to roll up a new connection?

Since the incident I have updated the getConnection() method that my app uses as so:

```
private Connection getConnection() {
    boolean failed = false;
    try{
        failed = !connection.isValid(1000);
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        System.out.println("WARNING: Connection not valid!");
    }
    try{
        failed = connection.isClosed();
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        System.out.println("WARNING: Connection is closed!");
    }
    if(failed){
        System.out.println("Renewing connection");
        this.initializeConnection();
    }
    return connection;
}
```

This is the output:

```
** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException
MESSAGE: The last packet successfully received from the server was54521 seconds
ago.The last packet sent successfully to the server was 54521 seconds ago, which
  is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consi
der either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your applic
ation, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the
 Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.

STACKTRACE:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet success
fully received from the server was54521 seconds ago.The last packet sent success
fully to the server was 54521 seconds ago, which  is longer than the server conf
igured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testi
ng connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server con
figured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property
 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1
074)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3246)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1917)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2536)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setCatalog(ConnectionImpl.java:4962)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData.getCallStmtParameterTypes(DatabaseMet
aData.java:1506)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData.getProcedureOrFunctionColumns(Databas
eMetaData.java:4120)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData.getProcedureColumns(DatabaseMetaData.
java:4057)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.determineParameterTypes(CallableStat
ement.java:809)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.<init>(CallableStatement.java:609)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4CallableStatement.<init>(JDBC4CallableStatement.j
ava:46)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor6.newInstance(Unknown Source)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.getInstance(CallableStatement.java:5
05)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.parseCallableStatement(ConnectionImpl.j
ava:3881)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareCall(ConnectionImpl.java:3965)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareCall(ConnectionImpl.java:3939)
        at com.protocase.hmiclient.db.HMIDatabaseAdapter.getAvailableBatchesForW
orkstation(HMIDatabaseAdapter.java:471)
        at com.protocase.hmiclient.views.WorkstationContainer.getBatches(Worksta
tionContainer.java:74)
        at com.protocase.hmiclient.views.BatchList.<init>(BatchList.java:55)
        at com.protocase.hmiclient.views.WorkstationContainer.goToBatchList(Work
stationContainer.java:56)
        at com.protocase.hmiclient.views.forms.BatchListControlPanel.refreshButt
onActionPerformed(BatchListControlPanel.java:118)
        at com.protocase.hmiclient.views.forms.BatchListControlPanel.access$200(
BatchListControlPanel.java:16)
        at com.protocase.hmiclient.views.forms.BatchListControlPanel$3.actionPer
formed(BatchListControlPanel.java:64)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
Source)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket wr
ite error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3227)
        ... 61 more


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exception suggests that you're opening the connection only once during application's startup and keeping forever open during the application's lifetime. This is bad. The DB will reclaim the connection sooner or later because it's been open for too long. You should close connections properly in the `finally` block of the very same `try` block as you're opening it and executing the query on it.

E.g.

```
public Entity find(Long id) throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = null;
    // ...

    try {
        connection = database.getConnection();
        // ...
    } finally {
        // ...
        if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
    }

    return entity;
}
```

If you have a performance concern regarding this (which is very reasonable as connecting is the most expensive task), then you should be using a connection pool. It also transparently handles this kind of "connection dropped" problems. For example, [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com/). Please note that also in case of a connection pool, you should still be closing the connections in the `finally` block as per the above JDBC code idiom. It will namely make them available for reuse.