# mybatis setting for mysql time-out on tomcat server

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, mybatis

using java7 tomcat7 and mybatis as ORM

config.xml is like this

```
<transactionManager type="JDBC" />
    <dataSource type="POOLED">
        <property name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url"    value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxxdb" />
        <property name="username" value="xxxxxxx" />
        <property name="password" value="xxxxxxx" />
        <property name="poolPingEnabled" value="true" />
        <property name="poolPingQuery" value="SELECT 1 " />
    </dataSource>
</environment>
```

mysql settings are all default set.
Hence interactive_timeout is 28800.
When I login my service, it fails for the first time, then it succeeds for the second time.
Above error sometimes happens even though re-login within 28800 seconds.
I paste the error message in server

```
2015 10:03:49 org.apache.ibatis.datasource.pooled.PooledDataSource warn
WARN: Execution of ping query 'SELECT 1' failed: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 30,572,290 milliseconds ago.  The     last packet sent successfully to the server was 1 milliseconds ago.
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:     The last packet successfully received from the server was 36,001,604 milliseconds ago.  The     last packet sent successfully to the server was 36,001,633 milliseconds ago. is longer than     the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or     testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured     values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true'     to avoid this problem.
### The error may exist in sql.xml
### The error may involve com.xxx.isRegistered-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: [query for login];
### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 36,001,604 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 36,001,633 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
```

I tried to add "autoReconnect=true" to the end of connection url, but it doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [Java app handling for connections getting dropped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218625/java-app-handling-for-connections-getting-dropped)

Reporting here [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc)'s answer:

> This exception suggests that you're opening the connection only once during application's startup and keeping forever open during the application's lifetime. This is bad. The DB will reclaim the connection sooner or later because it's been open for too long. You should close connections properly in the finally block of the very same try block as you're opening it and executing the query on it.
>
> E.g.
>
> ```
> public Entity find(Long id) throws SQLException {
>     Connection connection = null;
>     // ...
>
>     try {
>         connection = database.getConnection();
>         // ...
>     } finally {
>         // ...
>         if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
>     }
>
>     return entity;
> }
> ```
>
> If you have a performance concern regarding this (which is very reasonable as connecting is the most expensive task), then you should be using a connection pool. It also transparently handles this kind of "connection dropped" problems. For example, BoneCP. Please note that also in case of a connection pool, you should still be closing the connections in the finally block as per the above JDBC code idiom. It will namely make them available for reuse.